# Excel VBA code for replacing all "." by "," in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have an excel VBA macro in order to replace all "." (dot) by "," (comma) in a column in one sheet.

When I try to do it with the following code, it replaces only if the cell value is ".". But does not replace "." inside cell value (i.e : 1.16 should be turned to 1,16 in column D inside sheet5)

```
Sub ReplaceDoTwComma()

Worksheets("Sheet5").Columns("D").Replace _
What:=".", Replacement:=",", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

End Sub
```

Can someone give me the good code to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't have much information about your problem, but it's probably better solved by a different format for numeric cells (right-click, format) than a macro.  Your problem is probably that you aren't operating on text.

Comment: +1 Although it works for me. Be warned that it will change the cell contents to text.

Comment: Did some research and there is no good way to do this as a number (convert American to European commas and periods swap).  It has to be done as text.  Using a `.NumberFormat` does not work.

Comment: check the cell's formatting...

Comment: cell's formatting change does not help. I already use "," as a decimal separator in Control Panel > Regional Settings (system setting)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `LookAt:=xlPart` option.

```
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Columns("D").Replace _
        What:=sought, replacement:=replaced, LookAt:=xlPart
```

Comment: It's a simple answer to a simple question.  If you want the more complicated version you can drop it into an array.

Comment: but why would you complicate things? The code in the question works on its own. The issue is different and why not try to resolve the original issue? Dumping code is easy I can give you 50 versions to achieve the end result but there is no point.

Comment: new answer is going into the library.  Christ it's replacing some old code.

Comment: @vba4all Yeah that was some horrible over engineered code from when I first started using VBA and only understood arrays and control structures.

Comment: Thank you everybody, I have edited the code with @cheezsteak 's advice and it worked...Here is the final code that succeeded ;

Sub ReplaceDoTwComma()

Worksheets("Sayfa5").Columns("D").Replace _
What:=".", replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a macro for this, just select the column in question in excel > Crtl + h and in find what put "." and in replace with put "," and hit replace all