# Excel-vba Columns().replace for two columns

Tags: vba, excel

The code below changes comma to period for Column D.
I want it happen for both D & G.

```
Option Explicit
    Sub ReplaceDoTwComma()   
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("D").replace _
                What:=",", replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart    
    End Sub
```

I have tried

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("D").replace _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("G").replace _
```

or `Columns("D", "G")` or `Columns ("D" & "G")`  But no luck.

My good reference is [Excel VBA code for replacing all "." by "," in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998383/excel-vba-code-for-replacing-all-by-in-a-column)

Any guidance would be highly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do two seperate calls, remember the `_` indicates a line continuation so both lines need to be duplicated:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceDoTwComma()   
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("D").replace _
            What:=",", replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart    
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("G").replace _
            What:=",", replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart 
End Sub
```

Or

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceDoTwComma()   
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D,G:G").replace _
            What:=",", replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. SO doesn't allow me to approve it for now. Will do after 11 mins. Thanks again!